# magento - hide customizable products declinations on product collection

Tags: php, magento

I created some customizable product in my magento store. The collections appearing on category's pages is fine, but i made a custom product list block on homepage. He get the product list with

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)->getProductCollection()
```

In this list, the customizable product declination appears (ex: Tshirt-M and Tshirt-L if i get the size attribute as configurable).

Does anybody know the way magento filter the list for categories pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code you'll get all product from your category.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->    
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addCategoryFilter($category)
->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
->groupByAttribute('name');
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want a full product list, i want to filter declinations of a same product. Actually i get i my list "NewTshirt" , "NewTshirt - size S" , "NewTshirt - size M" , "NewTshirt - size L" , etc... And i just want the first item.

Comment: I must apologize, i just applied some filters to my product collection. After trying your full code, i only get 1 product (the first test product i created), due to the groupByAttribute filter. If i remove it, i get the exact list i got before. Maybe something's wrong with the product's configuration

Comment: You can remove groupBy Attribute, you should set your simple product to no visibility let just the configurable product to be seen.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i'll roll like this